# Does Python have a maximum group refer for regex (like Perl)?

Tags: python, regex, perl

**Context:**
When running a regex match in Perl, `$1`, `$2` can be used as references to captured regex references from the match, similarly in Python `\g<0>`,`\g<1>` can be used

Perl also has a `$+` special reference which refers to the captured group with highest numerical value

**My question:**
**Does Python have an equivalent of `$+` ?**

I tried `\g<+>` and tried looking in the documentation which only says:

> There’s also a syntax for referring to named groups as defined by the `(?P<name>...)` syntax. `\g<name>` will use the substring matched by the group named `name`, and `\g<number>` uses the corresponding group number. `\g<2>` is therefore equivalent to `\2`, but isn’t ambiguous in a replacement string such as `\g<2>0`. (`\20` would be interpreted as a reference to group 20, not a reference to group 2 followed by the literal character `'0'`.) The following substitutions are all equivalent, but use all three variations of the replacement string.

Comment: Not AFAIK. What's the use case? Why wouldn't you know the name or number of the last group?

Comment: @Barmar I have an alternative statement ROUGHLY like this 
(?: "(patternA*)" | '(patternB*)' | -(patternC*)- )
I want the maximum captured value, which is either 1,2 or 3 (only one of them is going to match),
I know I can use Python to check and compare and I also know I can use a different regex to solve this but I'm more interested to know if such a nifty thing like $+ exists or not

Comment: That does make sense, I didn't realize it returns the last matching group, not the last group.

Comment: Why not put all the alternatives in a single capture group? `(patternA|patternB|patternC)`?

Comment: @Barmar I would do so, that is the best solution (and the one I am going to use), but at this stage i was just more curious to see if it existed or not (I mainly program in python but was looking at a perl guide and felt jealous haha)

Comment: @akash  It turns out there is just such functionality with the method `captrures` in the `regex` module. See my answer, edited to include this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [captures](https://github.com/mrabarnett/mrab-regex#added-capturesdict-hg-issue-86) in the [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module provides the same functionality: it "*returns a list of all the captures of a group*."  So get the last one

```
>>> import regex
>>> str = 'fza'
>>> m = regex.search(r'(a)|(f)', str)
>>> print(m.captures()[-1])
f
```

When the `str` has `a` before `f` this code prints `a`.  This is the exact equivalent of Per's `$+`.  Here we do get *all* captures, not only the highest one, and other related methods. Follow the word "captures" in the linked docs.

---

Another option that fits the intended use, explained in a comment, is the *[branch reset group](https://github.com/mrabarnett/mrab-regex#branch-reset-)*, `(?|pattern)`.  It is also available in the [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module.

```
>>> import regex
>>> m = regex.search(r'(?|(a)|(b))', 'zba')
>>> m.group(1)
'b'
```

In short, with the branch reset `(?|(pA)|(pB)|(pC))` the whole pattern is *one* capture group (with three alternations), not three.  So you always know which is the "last" capture as there is only one, which has the match. This can be used with named capture groups as well.

This feature adds far more power as the pattern in `(?|...)` gets more complex. Find it in your favorite regex documentation. Here it is [in regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html), for example, and here are some Perl resources, [in perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#(?%7Cpattern)) and [an article in The Effective Perler](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/09/use-branch-reset-grouping-to-number-captures-in-alternations/).

Answer (score 2):

In most case, you'd just use one capture around the alternation.

```
(foo|bar|baz)
```

In more complex cases, you could filter out `None` results.

```py
import re
s = 'bar4'
m = re.search( r'foo([12])|bar([34])|baz([56])', s )
[ g for g in m.groups() if g is not None ]   # ['4']
```